# Add validator to stake pool - Custom Program Error 0xc

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, staking, solana-test-validator

I'm following the [Quick Start Guide](https://spl.solana.com/stake-pool/quickstart) for running a stake pool on the test validator, but I'm having trouble adding a validator ([Step 2](https://spl.solana.com/stake-pool/quickstart#step-2-add-validators-to-the-pool)).

`RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc`

The accounts have been funded with SOL and I've followed the guide by running each of the scripts.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `0xc` comes from the stake program, and means that there isn't enough SOL in the stake account in order to delegate it.  There was a recent change to make the minimum delegation equal to 1 SOL, which breaks the existing stake pool program on mainnet and devnet.

You'll need to run the newest version of the program by building it from source and including that in your test validator.  From the root of `solana-program-library`, you can do

```
cargo build-sbf --manifest-path stake-pool/program/Cargo.toml
solana-test-validator --bpf-program SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy target/deploy/spl_stake_pool.so
```